# Python - Original data matrix gets modified after for i, v in enumerate(): statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please see the code snippet below:

```
import numpy as np

# Load the .txt file in
myData = np.loadtxt('data.txt')

# Extract the time and acceleration columns
time = myData[:,0]

# Extract the linear acceleration columns
xLinearAcc = myData[:,4]
yLinearAcc = myData[:,5]
zLinearAcc = myData[:,6]

# Find the linear accelerations
xLinearAccSqr = myData[:,0]
for i, v in enumerate(xLinearAcc):
    xLinearAccSqr[i] = pow(v,2)
```

myData is my 2D data matrix. What I am trying to do is to extract the 4th column into an new array xLinearAcc. Then I square every single term in xLinearAcc and store them into another new array xLinearAccSqr.

(The reason why I have xLinearAccSqr = myData[:,0] is that if I do not have that line, the compiler always tells me that my  xLinearAccSqr is undefined. So I just randomly make it equal to the 1st column, because anyway later all the values get overwritten. Dunno whether this line causes trouble or not)

Then comes the problem.
The first column of myData gets strangely modified. I do not want this.
Anyone can help??
I will really appreciate the help!!~~

==========================UPDATES=======================================

Problem solved.
Post the solution here may help others.

Use

```
xLinearAccSqr = copy(myData[:,0])
```

Some how I guess Python passes the references instead of the values.
Thus, just make a copy then.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I reuse columns." "Have you considered not reusing columns?" -- Try initializing `xLinearAccSqr` to an actual empty matrix, rather than part of an existing one.

Comment: @Amber Thanks! Could you please show how to do it? Really new to Python. I also really wonder why the original one gets modified...

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy arrays behave differently from regular Python lists. In NumPy, [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) returns a view on the original array. That's why your original array gets modified when you modify the slice.

Create a new array using any of the [array creation routines](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html).